# Automated SQL Export Failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I have an automatic backup running each night through the Portal which should back up my Azure database to blob storage as a .bacpac file and up until Friday that had been working successfully. 
Each night I get an email error saying:

```
Automated SQL Export failed for myServer:myDatabase at 5/30/2016 11:35:39 PM. The temporary database copy was made, but this copy could not be exported to the .bacpac file.
```

Some tutorials suggest logging into the Portal and doing it manually. When I do this it works successfully and I am able to see the file without error. But on the following night, the process fails again (it doesn't recover itself from performing a manual backup). Is there a way to get more information on why it is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after further analysis I was able to pinpoint the root cause of my issue to a Stored Procedure. 
I had a Stored Proc which was explicitly referencing my database. Whenever the database backup is taken in Azure, it creates a temporary name and at that point, "breaks" the Stored Procedure as it was Self Referencing. 
Fixing the Stored Proc has resumed the automatic backups.

An example of a statement the Proc was calling was:

```
Select Name from MyDatabase.Dbo.MyTable
```

This should be rewritten as the following to make it exportable:

```
Select Name from Dbo.MyTable
```

Note that while I was able to obtain a more meaningful error using a local copy of Sql Server Management Studio, no error was present in the Azure Portal.
Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

In the [new Portal](https://portal.azure.com), you can find more information via audit log, database level operations will be logged there including import/export.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, although I see that screen, I don't see any errors listed.

Comment: I work on the product team for Automated Export and manual SQL Database export. We can help you debug this issue, but would need more information about your exports to determine the root cause. Could you reach out to me at ninarn AT microsoft DOT com?

Thanks.